# recorrer array php y eliminar repetidos

Tags: php, array

Buenas tardes: alguno puede indicarme como eliminar repetidos de un array, el que yo utilizao es:

```
$alumnos= Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Juan
            [nota] => 10
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => pedro
            [id] => 10
        )
        [3] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => pedro
            [id] => 10
        )
)
```

Comment: con `array_unique($alumnos, SORT_REGULAR);`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el criterio para determinar que el elemento esta repetido?

Comment: @Cris Nota de la documentación: *"Observe que array_unique() no está pensado para que trabaje con arrays multidimensionales"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que te sirva bro saludos.

```
// array de alumnos
    $alumnos = array(0=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 1=>array('alumno' => 'Gerardo', 'nota' => 10), 2=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 3=>array('alumno' => 'Jorgge', 'nota' => 10), 4=>array('alumno' => 'Josrge', 'nota' => 10), 5=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 6=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 7=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 8=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 9=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 10=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 11=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 12=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 13=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 14=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 15=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 16=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 17=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 18=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 19=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 20=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 21=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 22=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 23=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 24=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 25=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 26=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10), 27=>array('alumno' => 'Jorge', 'nota' => 10),);
    // array para guardar los alumnos sin repetir
    $alumnosNoRepetidos = array();
    // Recorremos el array de alumnos
    foreach ($alumnos as $key => $value) {
        // Verificamos si se repite los alumnos con el campo alumno
        if (!in_array($value['alumno'], array_column($alumnosNoRepetidos, 'alumno'))) {
            // Si no esta repetido lo agregamos al array 
            $alumnosNoRepetidos[] = $value;
        }
    }
    // Imprimimos el array 
    var_dump($alumnosNoRepetidos);

    // array original
    var_dump($alumnos);
```

Comment: Esta es la solucion! gracias Crack!

Answer (score 0):

Tal como te mencionaba en los comentarios, lo harías con [**`array_unique()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php), dentro de esta función se usó la constante predefinida [**`SORT_REGULAR`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/array.constants.php) para especificar el tipo de ordenamiento que se debe utilizar al eliminar elementos duplicados del array (más información en [**este enlace**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802680/array-unique-sort-regular-flag)). El código sería el siguiente:

```
<?php
  $alumnos = array(
     0 => array(
         "nombre" => "Juan",
         "nota" => 10
     ),
     1 => array(
         "nombre" => "Pedro",
         "id" => 10
     ),
     2 => array(
         "nombre" => "Pedro",
         "id" => 10
     )
  );
  
  $delete_duplicates = array_unique($alumnos, SORT_REGULAR);
  
  var_dump($delete_duplicates)
?>
```

**Output:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(4) "Juan"
    ["nota"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(5) "Pedro"
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
```